# How to build dynamic MVC4 View while accessing the Model in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to generate a html view from the Model in my **MVC 4** application, the **Model** is a list of elements and i want to generate form every element a list item on my view with the following format:

```
<div class="-index-toplevelMenuItems -t-index-toplevelMenuItems">
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/bullet.png")"/>
     <div>
         Model.Id
         <h6>Model.Date </h6>  
     </div>
</div>
```

- How can i build up my view and how do i open my model from JavaScript
  to insert the data in the above format? Is it better to build the
  view with the Razor syntax accessing the model?
- In which cases is advised to use the above mentioned two methods if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem, you can use vb.net code to do things like this, just use the **@** sign before it

```
@For Each oldRequest In Model.OldestRequests
    @<div class="-index-reminderItems" id="@oldRequest.RequestId">   
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/bullet.png")" />
        <div>
            @oldRequest.RequestName
            <h6>@oldRequest.CreatedOn</h6>  
        </div>
    </div> 
Next
```